# Using Titanium.Platform.takeScreenshot

Tags: screenshot, titanium

I'm evaluating using Titanium for a project that makes videos from browser based animations. I was hoping for a way to take screenshots from within the app for each frame. The documentation of takeScreenshot seems a little slim so I was hoping to ask before I build a prototype.

1. Does take screenshot get the full document, or just the visible content?
2. Does the screenshot include window chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from titanium QA was able to [answer the question](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/110101/using-titaniumplatformtakescreenshot). takeScreenshot actually takes a screenshot of the whole desktop.

Comment: There's also a very recent feature request for the capability to specify a size -- https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/projects/25719/tickets/546-feature-specify-size-of-screenshot-for-titaniumplatformtakescreenshot